# How to add a GIT pre-push hook to disallow pushing a Mock functionality

Tags: bash, git, hook

I want to write a Git pre-push hook to revoke pushing `[Mock]` or `[MockAttribute]` in files named *XXXController.cs* in **MyProj\Controllers** directory in my repository on the **develop** branch.
How to do that in **bash** or any other langugae? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a pretty easy to do thing. What have you tried already?

Comment: I have no idea in bash and using advanced Git commands

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a `pre-push` hook is suitable for this since `pre-commit` is probably a better choice, but here is a simple hook written in Bash that simply greps for a `[Mock]` or a `[MockAttribute]` occurrence:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# read the input from git (local refs and remote refs are "ignored" by reading into the _ variable)
while read _ LOCAL_OID _ REMOTE_OID; do
    #echo "running the pre-push check for the range $REMOTE_OID..$LOCAL_OID" >&2
    # git-rev-list produces commit IDs only, so process each commit id line by line
    while read OID; do
        #echo "verifying $OID" >&2
        # figure out files changed in the commit identified by the OID variable
        while read STATUS FILE_PATH; do
            # and if it's either added or modified ...
            case "$STATUS" in
            A|M)
                #echo "checking $FILE_PATH" >&2
                # ... run the check (-q produces no output but sets exit code only)
                git show "$OID:$FILE_PATH" | grep -qP '\[Mock(?:Attribute)?\]'
                # if grep found anything, 0 is returned, so we consider the check failed
                if test $? == '0'; then
                    echo -e "\e[31m$OID:$FILE_PATH does not pass the check\e[0m" >&2
                    exit 1
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                #echo "ignoring $FILE_PATH" >&2
                ;;
            esac
        done < <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r "$OID")
    done < <(git rev-list --reverse "$REMOTE_OID..$LOCAL_OID")
done

exit 0
```

Of course, using `grep` is not a reliable way of doing such a check, but there are probably more appropriate tools from the .NET world doing this.

Comment: Thank you @fluffy. I tried this  but there was an error:  Error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-push: No such file or directory
Error: waitpid for .git/hooks/pre-push failed: No child processes

Comment: @Morteza Are you using a Windows machine? I've just googled a few reasons why it may fail on those. Also, how does it work if you replace the hook with a simple echo-only script like `#!/bin/bash` and `echo 'all ok'`?

Comment: Yes I have a windows machine, but Git-Bash is installed on my machine.

Comment: @Morteza I'm no longer a Windows user, but please google for `Error: waitpid for .git/hooks/pre-push failed: No child processes` and it will result into something like https://superuser.com/questions/1465176/git-error-cannot-spawn-git-hooks-pre-push-no-such-file-or-directory -- perhaps some of the solutions may work, but this is definitely off-topic your question now.